# Android: How to Enable Samsung Multi-Window in Only One Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, samsung-mobile, multi-window

I have got the multi-window feature to work however, this is applied to all activities across the application. I would like to know is there a way to specify which activity that can use multi-window? For example, I have an introduction slider in which I would like to disable the feature and re-enable in the main activity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By launching activity in new task stack, you can accomplish this. But from user experience point of view, this may not be a good solution.

When app is in split screen mode, launch the activity, which you don't want do display in multi-window mode, by firing intent. Make sure that the target activity config in manifest is not multi-window enabled.

To go back to multi-window mode from full screen, you need to launch main activity in a new stack with below intent flags.

FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK